# Bean Validation fails, but action phase still executed

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, bean-validation

I am using a custom bean validation constraint. When bean validation constraint fails, `isValid` returns false. I would then expect, that the action phase will be skipped, which does not seem to be the case. The operation `doSomething` is still executed. What could be the cause of this? Thanks a lot in advance and let me know if you need more information.
Using MyFaces 2.0.15

Constraint Validator:

```
public class MyValidatorImpl extends ConstraintValidator<MyValidator, MyView>
{
 @Override
 public boolean isValid(...){
 return false;
 }
}
```

Model:

```
@MyValidator
public class MyViewImpl {
 public void doSomething(){
 System.out.println("Does something although Validation failed");
 }
}
```

View:

```
<h:commandButton value="Test"
                 action="#{myViewImpl.doSomething}" />
```

Update: In a previous software version we used the same myfaces implementation and this version worked fine. I've compared the xhtmls / java classes / validators, they are pretty much all the same. 
Any suggestions what  I could look for?

Comment: How exactly are you sure that the BV constraint is actually invoked? Which JSF impl/version are you using (older Mojarra versions had awkward bugs related to this)

Comment: what do you mean by bv constraint? when debugging, I can see that the validator is accessed and valid is false - using myfaces

Comment: The `isValid()` method. Note that you made some severe terminology mistakes in your initial question. I edited and fixed them. Please reread to learn the right terms.

Comment: You forgot to tell the version and whether you have tried the latest, if any.

Comment: Using MyFaces 2.0.15 and using the latest Version did not help

Comment: Wow, that's really ancient. Which "latest version" exactly have you tried?

Comment: Uhm, I must correct my previous answer, we were using version 2.0.13 and upgraded to 2.0.15 (I had mistaken that one for the "latest version").  unfortunately I cant transfer a newer Version (would take a couple of weeks). excluding the used implementation, could some other problem be the cause of this (changed configuration parameters etc.)? I think at some point the validators worked as intended, though im not 100% sure.